# Поиск по асоциативному массиву

Tags: php, алгоритм, json

Нужно реализировать поиск по асоциативному массиву

```
 function bankadata_getArray(){
  $source = file_get_contents('http://bank-ua.com/export/exchange_rate_cash.json');
  $source = json_decode($source);

  return $source;
}
```

Сам json http://pastebin.com/QZFpKr95.
Нужно найти для каждого банка курс валюты. Мой вариант

```
//получения данных о курсе $search - int адреса индекса банка, который нужен, $currency - валюта $type - покупука или продажа
function bankadata_cursEcho($search,$currency,$type)
 {
    $arr = bankadata_getArray();

    for($i=0;$i<=sizeof($arr);$i++)
    {
        if($arr[$i]->bankName==$arr[$search]->bankName && $arr[$i]->codeAlpha ==  $currency)
         {
           switch($type)
             {
                 case "buy":
                   return $arr[$i]->rateBuy;
                   break;
                 case "sell":
                     return $arr[$i]->rateSale;
                   break;
             }

         }

     }
 }
```

Но возвращает неверные данные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда я скормил json функции bankadata_getArray напрямую, все заработало.
Проверьте, что

1. файл доступен
2. В нем содержатся нужные данные в нужном формате
3. вы передаете правильные данные для поиска.

Отдельно отмечу, что лично мне вашей функцией пользоваться крайне неудобно: первый ее аргумент - это индекс в полученном массиве, по которому она ищет имя банка, по которому она потом начинает уже листать весь массив банков.
При этом, валюту вы уже передаете строкой(внезапно), тип тоже.

Comment: вы правы, невнимательно записывал в БД. Ищет имя банка в массиве, чтобы потом было проще записовать. По поводу передачи строкой, спасибо за замечание не знал что индексы асоциативного массива можно так передавать.